# Hiding the background from the leaflet map (i.e., Canada, Mexico) in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I have created the below map within the Shiny app context. I wonder how can I modify the code such that only US boundaries are shown (i.e., I want to hide Mexico, Canada, etc.). Below is the part of the code which I believe needs to be modified.

```
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                   options = providerTileOptions(
                     opacity = 0.5,
                   )
  ) %>%
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that what you describe is possible: the background tiles are pre-generated server side (which is why they are so fast) and distributed via CDN. Which is on one hand rather neat, but on the other requires certain standardization...